Online reference works on Italian dialects/regional terms
We have a very useful Meta question on What good reference works on Italian are available online?. Since this site is also open to some questions on dialects and regional variants of Italian, and we have been getting a lot of them recently, I would like to ask a parallel one.
Could you share links to dictionaries, grammars, and other useful resources on Italian dialects?
Please put one answer per region.

I've wikified everything, so that there's no need to do it manually

Thanks @DenisNardin - I'll remove the indication then.

Sicilia

Vocabolario Siciliano-Italiano di Giuseppe Tuccio.
Dizionario etimologico di forme dialettali di Arnaldo Moroldo.


Lombardia

Vocabolario Milanese-Italiano, Francesco Cherubini, 1840 ca., via Google Books.
Grammar and Vocabulary of the Eastern Lombard dialect of a town at the border between the Bergamo and Milan provinces.


I'm adding this answer mostly as an example. Disclaimer: I am a friend of the authors of http://xoomer.virgilio.it/kxqjfe/dialetweb/vucabula.htm .

Veneto

Dizionario del dialetto veneziano Third edition of the Italian-Venetian vocabulary by Giuseppe Boerio on archive.org
www.linguaveneta.net Website dedicated to the Venetian language by the Regione Veneto. It includes a few manuals, among which grammar manuals

In addition, it is not an online resource, but the Linguistic History of Venice by Ferguson is an extremely useful book both for the history of the Venetian language and its relationship with the Italian language.

Campania

Vocabolario di dialetto napoletano (parte prima) di Giuseppe Giacco.
Vocabolario di dialetto napoletano (parte seconda) di Giuseppe Giacco.
Lessico e Letteratura del Dialetto Napoletano di Salvatore Argenziano e Gianna De Filippis.


Piemonte

Vocabolario Piemontese-Italiano e grammatica piemontese di Michele Ponza, del 1847.
Nuovo dizionario piemontese – italiano di Giovanni Pasquali (Torino, 1869).
Dizionario piemontese italiano, latino e francese di Casimiro Zalli di Chieri (1830).


Toscana

Vocabolario del fiorentino contemporaneo dell'Accademia della Crusca.


Lazio

L'italiano nelle regioni: Roma e il Lazio, volume 1, di Pietro Trifone.
L'italiano nelle regioni: Roma e il Lazio, volume 2, di Pietro Trifone.


Liguria

Traduttore Italiano Genovese a cura di Franco Bampi

